# Scaling ImageViews with LinearLayout weights yields anomalies..?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-imageview

### Alright so I'm trying to have an image set up such that:

- the base of the image is lined up with the centre of the layout
- the image scales with the layout to fit in background image

What I've done to achieve that is the following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.9"/>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/widget_icon"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            android:src="@drawable/widget_icon"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

So I would expect the image to take up 10% of the space in the top half of the window no matter what the window height/width is set to but what I've come to realize is that it's not the case.. seems like the image doesn't scale down past its "real" size? I'm not entirely sure but I'm getting some really wonky and seemingly not linear scaling happening when it comes to widget_icon. Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into the [ImageView ScaleTypes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

It looks like you might also not understand how weight works

typically you would set width or height to 0dp and then set the weight.  if you have 2 items and you set the weights to 1 they would both take up half of the respective width or height.. if you set one to 1 and the other to 2, then the one set to 2 would take up 2/3 of the layout's width or height and the one set to 1 would be 1/3

hope that helps

Comment: So if I'm getting this right you're saying the problem arises from me setting the imageview's height to wrap_content rather than 0dp?

Comment: yes, i believe so.. if i understand the question properly, but you should also take into consideration HOW you want the image to scale.. which is why i add the link to scaleType

Comment: Tried it with 0dp, seems to solve the issue. Thanks! The default scale works fine as well with this.